# How to get value from input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some problem to get value from input field.
 Some input field is a result from calculation process, such as #t1_potensi and #t2_potensi. While #aliran is the result of the overall calculation process.

This is my HTML code.

```
<input oninput="hitung()" name="v_potensi" id="v_potensi" type="text" placeholder="liter . . ." />        
<input oninput="hitung()" name="a_potensi" id="a_potensi" type="text" placeholder="menit . . ." />
<input oninput="hitung()" name="b_potensi" id="b_potensi" type="text" placeholder="menit . . ." />

<input oninput="hitungT1()" name="kecepatan_air" id="kecepatan_air" type="text" placeholder="km/jam . . ." />
<input oninput="hitungT1()" name="jarak1" id="jarak1" type="text" placeholder="kilometer . . ." />

<input oninput="hitungT2()" name="kecepatan_back" id="kecepatan_back" type="text" placeholder="km/jam . . ." />
<input oninput="hitungT2()" name="jarak2" id="jarak2" type="text" placeholder="kilometer . . ." />

<!-- #t1_potensi = 0.65 + ((60 / #kecepatan_air) * #jarak1) -->
<input readonly="readonly" oninput="hitung()" name="t1_potensi" id="t1_potensi" type="text" placeholder="menit . . ." />

<!-- #t2_potensi = 0.65 + ((60 / #kecepatan_back) * #jarak2) -->
<input readonly="readonly" oninput="hitung()" name="t2_potensi" id="t2_potensi" type="text" placeholder="menit . . ." />

<!-- #aliran = (#v_potensi / (#a_potensi + #b_potensi + #t1_potensi + #t2_potensi)) - 0.1 -->
<input readonly="readonly" name="aliran" id="aliran" type="text" placeholder="liter/menit . . ." />
```

I use javascript to do the calculation process, to get a result for #t1_potensi and #t2_potensi. My problem start when i try to calculate overall (#aliran), my javascript function in particular to obtain the overall result can not work properly. Here my javascript for #t1_potensi, #t2_potensi, and #aliran.

```
//To get #t1_potensi    
function hitungT1() {
                var kecKm = document.getElementById('kecepatan_air').value;
                var d1 = document.getElementById('jarak1').value;
                var result = document.getElementById('t1_potensi');
                //convert Km/jam to mph 
                var kecMph = Math.round(kecKm * 0.621371192);
                //convert liter to miles
                var d1Miles = d1 * 0.621371192;
                var x = 60 / kecMph;
                var kali = x.toFixed(1) * d1Miles.toFixed(2);
                var hasil = 0.65 + kali;
                result.value = hasil.toFixed(2);
            }
//To get #t2_potensi
function hitungT2() {
                var kecKm = document.getElementById('kecepatan_back').value;
                var d2 = document.getElementById('jarak2').value;
                var result = document.getElementById('t2_potensi');
                //convert Km/jam to mph
                var kecMph = Math.round(kecKm * 0.621371192);
                //convert liter to miles
                var d1Miles = d2 * 0.621371192;
                var x = 60 / kecMph;
                var kali = x.toFixed(1) * d1Miles.toFixed(2);
                var hasil = 0.65 + kali;
                result.value = hasil.toFixed(2);
            }

//To get #aliran
function hitung() {
                var vol = document.getElementById('v_potensi').value;
                var a = document.getElementById('a_potensi').value;
                var b = document.getElementById('b_potensi').value;
                var t1 = document.getElementById('t1_potensi').value;
                var t2 = document.getElementById('t2_potensi').value;
                var hasil = document.getElementById('aliran');
                //convert liter to galon
                var galon = Math.round(vol * 0.264172051);
                var sumT = t1 + t2;
                var sum = a + sumT + b;
                var dev = galon / sum;
                var result = Math.round(dev - 0.1);
                hasil.value = result;
            }
```

Does anyone can help me to solve my problem? or maybe make my javascript function more efficient. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseFloat()` on the numbers you're getting with document.getElementById('...').value:

```
//To get #t1_potensi    
function hitungT1() {
            var kecKm = parseFloat(document.getElementById('kecepatan_air').value);
            var d1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('jarak1').value);
            var result = document.getElementById('t1_potensi');
            //convert Km/jam to mph 
            var kecMph = Math.round(kecKm * 0.621371192);
            //convert liter to miles
            var d1Miles = d1 * 0.621371192;
            var x = 60 / kecMph;
            var kali = x.toFixed(1) * d1Miles.toFixed(2);
            var hasil = 0.65 + kali;
            result.value = hasil.toFixed(2);
        }
//To get #t2_potensi
function hitungT2() {
            var kecKm = parseFloat(document.getElementById('kecepatan_back').value);
            var d2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('jarak2').value);
            var result = document.getElementById('t2_potensi');
            //convert Km/jam to mph
            var kecMph = Math.round(kecKm * 0.621371192);
            //convert liter to miles
            var d1Miles = d2 * 0.621371192;
            var x = 60 / kecMph;
            var kali = x.toFixed(1) * d1Miles.toFixed(2);
            var hasil = 0.65 + kali;
            result.value = hasil.toFixed(2);
        }

//To get #aliran
function hitung() {
            var vol = parseFloat(document.getElementById('v_potensi').value);
            var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('a_potensi').value);
            var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('b_potensi').value);
            var t1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('t1_potensi').value);
            var t2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('t2_potensi').value);
            var hasil = document.getElementById('aliran');
            //convert liter to galon
            var galon = Math.round(vol * 0.264172051);
            var sumT = t1 + t2;
            var sum = a + sumT + b;
            var dev = galon / sum;
            var result = Math.round(dev - 0.1);
            hasil.value = result;
        }
```

Also, it's a bit tricky to me why you call the `hitung()` function only after editing one of the first three text boxes. Why not call all three functions every time any field is changed? Wouldn't that be better?

Up to you. Also, after you've placed `parseFloat` calls like above, please use `console.log(string or variable to log)`, e.g. `console.log('dev is: ' + dev)`. That way you can easily debug your code - see what all the values are during any calculation.

Also, do you really need to round the final result?